# WooCommerce product image swap hiding first image on rollover

Tags: woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce shop and on the shop page when I rollover an image it swaps it for the first image in the gallery by default which is fine.  The problem i have is my images are transparent png's and so as the second image appears you can still see the first image beneath it.

Is it possible to hide the first image with `dsiplay:none;`  if so how do i find the correct css class, as i have spent days looking but can not find it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just added a background to the second image so that it hid the first

```
 .secondary-image {
      background:red!important;
 }
```